# Ubuntu 16.04: Install older .deb file that is not found in newer Ubuntu LTS

Tags: updates, 16.04, deb

I am installing some VPN application on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but it ran into some issues. Later I found out that libjsoncpp0 is required for the VPN application to be successfully installed.

I know the basic of what is the function of the deb package. 
My questions are:

1. This libjsoncpp0 is from a previous versions of Ubuntu. Why isn't this package come with default Ubuntu 16.04?
2. If I installed this manually, will I face any issues in the future when doing upgrading? Is it safe in term of security since they had decided to remove from the main repo?

Comment: Installing the package libjsoncpp-dev doesn't help you?

Comment: 1. As Ubuntu is a Debian derivative, if a package is gone from Debian, it will also disappear from Ubutnu. You might want to research it to verify what happened 2. Possibly, especially if that package is no longer supported by anyone.

Comment: There is http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libjsoncpp1 is Xenial.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and simply installed an archived version of libjsoncpp0 for Ubuntu Trusty. Just download and install it with Ubuntu Software Center from:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libjsoncpp0/download

Comment: I recommend also adding the Trusty repositories to your software sources, in order to automatically get bugfix and security updates.